# Append observation at end of row from another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data with 900 rows and 400 columns. Each two column carry particular information. Let me say, there are A B C D column, I will like append C and C column just end of A and B column.

For example:

---

```
A   B   C   D   E   F  
3   4   5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12  13  14
```

to change to

```
Column 1   Column 2 
3            4 
9            10
5            6
11           12
7            8
13           14
```

Comment: Fyi, you can indent four spaces to make code blocks, or highlight and press CTRL+K.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you just asking how to append a data point to a row?

Comment: yes, just append the data to the row.

Comment: As a side note, this looks an awful lot like a reshape operation. Check out the `reshape2` package.

Comment: thanks for useful information! What strategies would you suggest if I have to retain the first column (not shown in above example) and stack every two column of the original datafram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the new `data.frame` by stacking the odd and even columns of the original `df` into 2 new columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Column1 = unlist(df[,c(T,F)]), 
                  Column2 = unlist(df[,c(F,T)]))
> df1
#   Column1 Column2
#A1       3       4
#A2       9      10
#C1       5       6
#C2      11      12
#E1       7       8
#E2      13      14
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `o` is all numeric, convert to a matrix:

```
o <- read.table(text='A   B   C   D   E   F  
3   4   5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12  13  14', header=TRUE)

o <- as.matrix(o)
```

First, you actually have pairs of columns, so this could be thought of as a 3D array. We can reshape to 3d in-place:

```
dim(o) <- c(2,2,3)
```

So `o` looks like this:

```
> o
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    9   10

, , 2   

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    6
[2,]   11   12

, , 3   

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    8
[2,]   13   14
```

Using aperm to move the indices, and  `dim<-` to reshape, we can get pretty close:

```
>`dim<-`(aperm(o, c(3,1,2)), c(6,2))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    5    6
[3,]    7    8
[4,]    9   10
[5,]   11   12
[6,]   13   14
```

If you actually want it in exactly the 2d order above you need a transpose:

```
> t(`dim<-`(aperm(o, c(2,1,3)), c(2,6)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    9   10
[3,]    5    6
[4,]   11   12
[5,]    7    8
[6,]   13   14
```